# jQuery animation for onClick is not working for continuous clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code to show a "Copied!" message when clicking on a button. I have added some jQuery codes to animate the message. The problem is, The message is not showing if I click the button twice or more than twice within a short period. And also with delay clicks, message is showing for three clicks only. After the third click, the message is not showing. How can I solve this?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $(".note").show();
  $(".note").css("opacity", "1");
  $('.note').animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 2200);
  $(".note").hide(2200);
});
```

```css
.note {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #4ea2e2;
        color: #fff;
        left: 35%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you have total 4 seconds of animation, you can try removing the delay from `hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the animate before start another one.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $(".note").stop();
 $(".note").show();
  $(".note").css("opacity", "1");
  $('.note').animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 2200);
});
```

```css
.note {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #4ea2e2;
        color: #fff;
        left: 35%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is working on multiple clicks too. But due to the long time you gave for the animation, it is not rendering. It will start again once the first animation is completed. You can inspect the button inside chrome and see the values changing. Once all the calculations are done, you can click again and it will work again.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $(".note").show();
  $(".note").css("opacity", "1");
  $('.note').animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 200);
  $(".note").hide(200);
});
```

```css
.note {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #4ea2e2;
        color: #fff;
        left: 35%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your animation time is too long thus preventing multiple css animations from happening. Instead of animating the `opacity` yourself, you can use jQuery's inbuilt method [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to fade to `0` opacity.

See working example:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".note").show();
  $(".note").fadeOut(2200);
});
```

```css
.note {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4ea2e2;
  color: #fff;
  left: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rearranging you code:

```
 $("button").on("click", function(){      
     $(".note").css("opacity", "1");
     $(".note").show();
     $('.note').animate({
         opacity: "0"
     }, 2200);
     $(".note").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `stop()` methdo to stop the animation for each click, and add the `hide()` method when animation is complete

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".note").stop(true, true);
  $(".note").show();
  $(".note").css("opacity", "1");
  $('.note').animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 2200, function() {
    //animation complete
    $(".note").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.note {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4ea2e2;
  color: #fff;
  left: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $('.note').fadeIn(2200);
  $('.note').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.note {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4ea2e2;
  color: #fff;
  left: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="note">
  <span>Code Copied!</span>
</div>
```